# How can I search for strings in a log file where the time listed is less than a value?

Tags: regex, date, time, awk, grep

I have a log file containing credit card request/response information. This log continuously runs, generating strings with different dates and times. I need to find only strings less than a particular date and time within the entire log. Below is a portion of my log, and an example using grep to find strings of a particular date.

```
Friday, June 19, 2015 11:57:45 PM : Request:Capture
Order Number 000001
Credit Card Type: VI
```

Using grep -A 2 --text "June 19, 2015" FirstData.log > FirstDataDate.log, I can get all entries from June 19th 2015. Being that this is a restaurant open past midnight, the log switches to June 20th 2015 for transactions taking place after 12:00 am. However, I need all transactions for the "business" day (10:00 am June 18 - 2:00 am June 19). Can I somehow use the time listed in the same string? Would a regex or awk command help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, this may work. I don't know if using RegExs is the best way to solve this problem, but I can offer you a RegEx that will solve the specific problem you  mentioned in your post (June 19 - 20) where the dates and closing hours can be adjusted fairly easily. You can still handle it all with grep, which is kind of a neat way of problem-solving without full-scale programming.

`June\s20,\s2015\s(12|[1-4]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\sAM`

Substitute the date for whatever you'd like. Also, note the [1-4] character class; substitute the 4 for whatever closing hour you'd like, and the RegEx will match all the way up to #:59:59 (e.g. 4:59:59). Let me know if this addresses what you were after. If not, I'd be happy to offer more assistance.

Comment: Wouldn't this search for a specific time? Essentially I need to search the log for a variable date and time range.. In this case all entries between 10:00 am day1 to 2:00 am day2

Answer (score 0):

This will print lines from noon June 19 until noon June 20:

`sed -n -r '/June 19.+PM/,/June 20.+PM/p' FirstData.log | head -n -1`

The time range 10:00 AM to 2:00 AM is a little too complicated for a `sed` one-liner. This bash script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
day1="June 19, 2015"
day2="June 20, 2015"
open=$(date -d "$day1 10:00:00 AM" +%s)
close=$(date -d "$day2 02:00:00 AM" +%s)
matched=false
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ "$day1" ]]; then
        date=$(date -d "${line//M :*/M}" +%s)
        if [[ $date -ge $open ]]; then
            matched=true
        fi
    fi
    if [[ $line =~ "$day2" ]]; then
        date=$(date -d "${line//M :*/M}" +%s)
        if [[ $date -ge $close ]]; then
            matched=false
        fi
    fi
    if ($matched == true); then
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

Save the script as `grepday.sh`, make it executable, and run it with `./grepday.sh < FirstData.log`

Comment: This got me closer, as it allowed for a date/time span. However, I'm not familiar enough with regex to make this work for my scenario. What regex input could I use to search for June 19, 2015 10:00:00 AM to June 20, 2015 2:00:00 AM?

Comment: I updated my answer with a bash script that should do what you need.